# Every .NET WinForms application crashes when run outside Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This might very well be very silly problem, so I apologize in advance.

The problem is as follows:

Every application with windows forms (even very simple application) I try to put together under visual studio 2010, even if it runs fine when run from IDE - debug mode, no errors, no unhandled exceptions, no crashes, no anything. No warnings from the compiler (I've got my warnings level set to 4). Whenever I try to run it without debug mode, or outside IDE, it runs for about 1 minute, and then closes itself, regardless of whether I interact with the application or not. No error message is displayed, no anything. It just disappears. I have tried to search windows event log, no result. Maybe I need to change settings of event log?

What makes this problem different from other similar issues described on stackoverflow is, that it happens with every application compiled under visual studio, the "crash" happens every time the application is run, and happens in a very short time.

Here is the main piece of source code of one such sample single-form dummy application I have written:

```
    namespace pj2_lastAttemptApp
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label1.Text = "You have written: " + textBox1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

And yet even this crashes unless in debug mode.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, my OS is Windows Vista Business.
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: this is the attached debugger output:

```
  'pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
  'pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\User_data\<my user name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\pj2_lastAttemptApp\pj2_lastAttemptApp\bin\Release\pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe', Symbols loaded.
  'pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
  'pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
  'pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
  The program '[1852] pj2_lastAttemptApp.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
  The program '[3436] pj2_lastAttemptApp.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Sounds like either corruption or a virus.

Comment: Vista that's a problem. Can you clarify if the process is still alive after the magic act? +1 this could be a hard problem to fix IF a debugger cannot be attached to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running something you've compiled on *another* computer? That should sort out the sheep from the goat pretty fast..

Comment: Have you reviewed the event logs to see if there are any log entries corresponding to these crashes?

Comment: Assuming this all the code you have, it sounds like corruption/virii, as Douglas said.  Do you have some sort of run-time "debug mode" built-into your program, outside of your compiler?  If so, posting the messages from this may also be useful for determining what your problem is, as having a feature like that could help to serve as a sort of breakpoint for a lot of the more ambiguous errors that can occur.

Comment: You might try handling some events like AppDomain.ProcessExit, Application.ApplicationExit, AppDomain.FirstChanceException, Application.ThreadException. Also I would reinstall the .Net framework.

Comment: Process dies when the form disappears.

Comment: Yes it is all the code I have, except for that which was generated by the designer, as you have probably guessed. I have tried to run it on another computer (I should have done it before of course), and it works. Problem is, that computer is Win7, not Vista, so now I don't know if this is Vista problem or my PC problem.

Comment: I have attached visual studio debugger to the process, I am not sure if that's of any help. The program crashed as before, output was not very illuminating, see below

Comment: No crash, it just exited cleanly.  Override the OnFormClosing() method. Attach a debugger and set a breakpoint on the new method.  Post the call stack.

Comment: Try to run the app with WinDBG to get more information

Comment: In addition to Thomas suggestion, I recommend to check the event log of .NET Framework.

Comment: This is somewhat embarassing ... last night I got some automatic updates installed, among them the .NET framework updates and - the problem seems to be gone. Anyway thanks to everybody for their help.

Comment: That implies that my suggestion of reinstalling the framework would have worked. :)

Comment: Try change the .Net Framework version in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the application directly of exe file, try to set "Local copy" = true for each assembly in the References node and rebuild the project. Execute and try it if run it without problems.